# Setting default JRE version via batch file

Tags: windows, batch-file, registry, java

I have JRE 6 and JRE 7 both installed on my Windows 7 workstation. I want to set the default Java to JRE 6.

I've tried setting the JAVA_HOME variable to  C:\Program Files (x86)\Java\JRE6\bin and I've also tried messing with the registry.... none of these are working for me

I don't want to uninstall and i don't want to use the GUI control panal Java Console to disable JRE 7.

I need to automate a way to set JRE 1.6 as the default java?

Comment: As the jre is used mainly by the browsers and they search the current version in registry I think you should see what was a a problem with editing registry values.The version (if the machine is 64 bit) is written n `\HKLM\SOFTWARE\Wow6432\JavaSoft\Java Runtime Environment\CurrentVersion` and you just need to set the version ot 1.7

Answer (score 1):

You should set the /bin/java (java.exe in MSWindows) in your path and put in in the first place.[Steps 16, 17, and 18](http://www.strongkey.org/resources/documentation/installation/howto-install-jdk1.5.0-windows.html)

Answer (score 0):

`JAVA_HOME` should point root folder of java e.g. `C:\Program Files (x86)\Java\JRE6`. Please try.